# How to trim String during JAXB MARSHALLING

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, trim

I am using JAXB to marshal Java Objects to XML.

http://highlevelbits.com/2009/08/jaxb-with-maven_16.html

I have tried setting the collapsedstringadapter Adapter to my JAXB generated classes.
But it appears collapsedstringadapter will only Trim the String values during unmarshal and during marshal it returns the String un-trimmed.

Can some one point to me on how to trim String during marshal via JAXB?

Answer (score 1):

Write and configure your own adapter? Just as you'd configure `CollapsedStringAdapter`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="myschema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:globalBindings>
            <xjc:javaType name="java.lang.String" xmlType="xs:string"
                adapter="com.acme.foo.bind.annotation.adapters.BiCollapsedStringAdapter"/>
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```